# What is the equivilent of whatis in powershell

Tags: powershell

I have learned the basics of using UNIX but I am now trying to learn how to use powershell. Most of the commands are similar or easy to find the equivalent of. However, I have not found the equivalent of whatis. Is there an equivalent? I have tried searching online but the search engines take "whatis" as being "what is". Is there anybody that knows what the equivalent is or if there is an equvalent at all?

Comment: use `Get-Help` to display help about cmdlets and concepts. It is your best friend when you can't remember commands

Comment: I would also suggest `Get-Alias` to see which UNIX commands map to Powershell cmdlets

Comment: You can even create you own aliases. You can add whatis to map to get help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `Get-Help` to display help about cmdlets and concepts. It is your best friend when you can't remember commands

```
Get-Help <cmdlet>
```

I would also suggest `Get-Alias` to see which UNIX commands map to PowerShell cmdlets

You can even create you own aliases. You can add whatis to map to get help.

```
New-Alias whatis Get-Help
```

which would then allow you to do

```
whatis <cmdlet>
```

For good measure, the second best command to get familiar with is

```
Get-Command
```

Using `Get-Command` along side `Get-Help` will help (pun intended) you get up to speed with PowerShell. I do suggest using a filter with `Get-Commad` as the list tends to be very long. It allows wildcard filters

```
Get-Command *-command
```